# How to open a url page for the first tab window from a second tab window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My question is, suppose you have a tab that opens another second tab on a different window, is there a way where the second tab window can open a url page for the first tab window, example is paypal checkout, when initiating a transaction, another tab window is opened, and when the transaction is done, the paypal checkout tab window closes and opens a redirect url (completed transaction) for the first tab window, so is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The way you'd do this is by using the **window.opener** property:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Also, a less elegant way to take action in one window when something happens in another would be to poll for a **document.cookie** change in the first window, knowing the value that will be set in the second when a certain condition is met.

The second approach would require both pages to be on the same domain, or subdomains.